# Why is this region in RegionPlot3D wrong?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, regions

I believe this is simple, but I can't wrap my head around forming region for `RegionPlot3D`.

 I have been reading and trying to understand how to write the region but not success.
So, here is the problem.

I have this graph:

```
plot1 = Plot[{x^2, -x + 2}, {x, -1, 2}, GridLines -> Automatic];
plot2 = Plot[{x^2, -x + 2}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}, 
   FillingStyle -> Lighter[Pink, 0.9]];
Show[plot1, plot2, 
 AxesLabel -> (MaTeX[#, Magnification -> 2] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image]

Now I want to plot the shape formed when I rotate the shading part around y-axis. 
This is my attempt but the plot doesn't look right.

```
RegionPlot3D[-1 <= x <= 1 && x^2 + z^2 <= (2 - x)^2 && 
   1 <= y <= 2 || -1 <= x <= 1 && x^2 + z^2 <= (x^2)^2 && 
   0 <= y <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

What is wrong here?
How can I plot it?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
reg=With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], h = z}, 
 ImplicitRegion[{h <= -r + 2, h >= r^2}, {x, y, z}]]
reg//Region
reg//Volume
```

> `(5 π)/6`

```
With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], h = z}, 
 RegionPlot3D[{h <= -r + 2 && h >= r^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 
   0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is nice. Would it also be okay to point out what is wrong in my plot?

Comment: @hana  In your original code, change something as below:  `RegionPlot3D[-1 <= x <= 1 && x^2 + z^2 <= (2 - y)^2 && 
   1 <= y <= 2 || -1 <= x <= 1 && x^2 + z^2 <= y && 
   0 <= y <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50]`

Comment: @hana perhaps a noteworthy comment: the option `PlotPoints -> 50` is redundant. I tried it without that and it still worked! I think cvgmt just fixed a typo from the OP, that's what was going off.

Comment: @bmf I think it is to make the plot smoother?

Comment: @hana yes, I was trying to say that it is not necessary since cvgmt fixed a small typo in the OP. I agree with you

Comment: @bmf nope, he fixed my mistakes in the equaitons like x^2 + z^2 <= (2 - y)^2, etc. You probably didn't notice them.

Comment: @hana that's also quite likely. it's very possible that I missed something :)